# for IMAP php5-imap or dovecot?

Tags: nginx, imap

I'm confused here while trying to get IMAP going on ubuntu 14.04, nginx, php-5

There is a package installed called php5-imap, is that all i need or do i need to install dovecot still?

I'm not connecting through in IMAP:

```
telnet mydomain.com 143
Trying 43.55.11.88...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

and:

```
netstat -an | grep :143
```

gives a blank line (nothing)

What should I be looking for to get IMAP going?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

php5-imap is a PHP module to communicate with IMAP Servers. It is typically used by Webmail applications.

dovecot is an imap server. It looks like you are looking for an imap server

Comment: ok, so I do need to install dovecot then right?

Comment: when installing dovecot it says: Host name: localhost for ssl, do i leave that as it is?

Comment: Please follow the documentation on how to setup dovecot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot

Comment: No, I was asking about during installation it pops up with a ssh screen asking you to input hostname, I just left it as 'localhost' don't know if this is correct or should I have put 'domain.com' in there? there was no info about that in the link provided aswell